# how to show alertdialog in URLSession

Tags: ios, swift

I try to get message from server using URLSession.

I want to show an alert dialog using a received message

my code...

```
func requestGet(url: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool, Any) -> Void) {
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return
    }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error: error calling GET")
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            print("Error: Did not receive data")
            return
        }
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200 ..< 300) ~= response.statusCode else {
            print("Error: HTTP request failed")
            return
        }
        guard let output = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) else {
            print("Error: JSON Data Parsing failed")
            return
        }
        
        completionHandler(true, output.result)
    }.resume()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    
    var noticeTitle = ""
    var noticeMessage = ""
    requestGet(url:"https://localhost:3000/notice") { (success, data) in
        let cc = data as! ContentString
        noticeTitle = cc.notice_title
        noticeMessage = cc.notice_desc
    }
    self.makeAlertDialog(title:noticeTitle, message:noticeMessage)
}

func makeAlertDialog(title: String, message: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let alertDeleteBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "오늘 하루 그만 보기", style: .destructive) { (action) in
        print("[SUCCESS] Dialog Cancel Button Click!")
    }
    let alertSuccessBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "닫기", style: .default) { (action) in
    }
    
    alert.addAction(alertDeleteBtn)
    alert.addAction(alertSuccessBtn)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I confirmd 'noticeTitle', 'noticeMessage' is ""..
because dataTask is async..

1. how to save a message on local variable.
2. how to show alert dialog
3. self.present not working..why?

Comment: You should (a) call it from inside the `requestGet` closure; and (b) remember to dispatch `present` to the main queue.

Comment: Unrelated, but I’d also suggest not defining `ContentString` with properties with underscores, but rather use traditional camelCase, but set the `keyDecodingStrategy` of the `JSONDecoder` to `.convertFromSnakeCase`. Also, rather than `(Bool, Any)`, I might suggest `Result<ContentString, Error>` parameter.

Comment: I fixed it...use a main queue..thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Dialog not show correct message

Hey, so you're making the the alert `outside` the url session closure, so your code is running like this:

ViewDidLoad() -> Trigger URL Session -> self.makeAlertDialog -> Set NoticeTitle and message variables -> End

There is nothing telling the code to re-run the `self.makeAlertDialog` function. To fix this, change your code to:

```swift
requestGet(url: "https://localhost:3000/notice") { [weak self] (success, data) in
    guard let cc = data as? ContentString else {
        return
    }

    noticeTitle = cc.notice_title
    noticeMessage = cc.notice_desc
    self?.makeAlertDialog(title:noticeTitle, message:noticeMessage)
}
```

This will cause the dialog to be created after the variables have been set and thus, after the network request has finished.

### Why is the Dialog not being shown

I'm afraid I can't find a valid reason why this is happening, but please make the change as before, then let me know if it fixes this issue.